# "returns(function() external fun)" a function can be returned in a call.?

Tags: solidity, brownie

In the solidity documentation I find this example. I'm trying to understand what is going on here. Does it mean that I can return a function?
Is assembly used to make the dynamic return of other contract functions?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.10 <0.9.0;

contract C {
    // Assigns a new selector and address to the return variable @fun
    function combineToFunctionPointer(address newAddress, uint newSelector) public pure returns (function() external fun) {
        assembly {
            fun.selector := newSelector
            fun.address  := newAddress
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that's right, you can return function types and you are also able to change their selector/address to the one of another

```
contract ConA {

    function combineToFunctionPointer(address newAddress, uint newSelector) public pure returns (function() external fun) {
        assembly {
            fun.selector := newSelector// bb29998e -> test(address)
            fun.address  := newAddress// address of ConB
        }
        //fun will point to test of ConB
    }
}

contract ConB {

        function test(address a) external view{
        ...do something...

    }
}
```

you can find more information about function types here:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#function-types